# Fetch products from the Tradedoubler API when there's no Ruby library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'd like to fetch products from the Tradedoubler API into my Rails app (similar to the way I did it for the Amazon API), but they don't have a Ruby library and I have no idea how to access them "manually".

http://dev.tradedoubler.com/products/advertiser/

Does anybody have any suggestions?